# filereader is undefined in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, filereader

I'm using the following to process a file upload via FileReader API, and I don't seem to be getting a reader object in Firefox 31.0:

```
var processFileUpload = function(event) {
    var fileInput = event.target;
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    if (typeof file !== 'undefined' && file !== null && file.hasOwnProperty('size') && file.size > 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            file_url = reader.result;
            saveFile(file_url, file.name, file.type, file_category);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
};
```

In firebug, I have a breakpoint on two lines:

```
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

and

```
file_url = reader.result;
```

When I select a file, it breaks as expected on the first breakpoint: **reader.readAsDataURL(file);**

To get to that point, it *must* have gone through **var reader = new FileReader();**

The values of the relevant variables at that point are:

```
file = { size: 21720, type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", name: "Example.docx", path: "", lastModifiedDate: Date 2014-08-14T09:29:49.000Z, mozFullPath: "" }

reader = undefined
```

The breakpoint on **file_url = reader.result;** never gets hit.

Why is **reader** undefined? Why is its onload got getting called? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors. I don't get any response at all. If I take all the breakpoints out, the code that should be executed in reader.onload() simply isn't called.

Comment: Try adding a `onerror` handler to see if an error fires.

Comment: Well, that's weird. I added an onerror, which doens't get fired, but now I get a FileReader object, and it all works :/